# Search files and Generate MD5 Hash value

Tags: powershell

Hi Guys I am facing an issue while searching and Generating hash value of files. The problem which I am facing is at the time of writing its output 
into a Out.txt file. I want to write the output result of both files Data1.txt and SqlData.txt but unfortunately it Erases the first files Output and Saving the last file output result that is SqlData.txt value below is the short Description of code for understanding the code

**#File1.txt file contains the list of two files Data1.txt and SqlData.txt which i want to search**
**#Dir1.txt file contains path of Directory (C:) in which i want to search the $arr output files**

*Code so far which I have tried.*

```
cls
$arr = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Direct\File1.txt"  
$d = Get-Content $arr
Foreach ($objFile in $d) {
$c = $objFile.Name
$a = Get-Content "C:\Direct\Dir1.txt" 
$e = Get-ChildItem -Path $a -Filter $objFile -Recurse  -Force -ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue # Searching the Files
$k = Get-Hash $e >  C:\Direct\Reverse\Out.txt #Fetching the Hash value of files and writing output into Out.txt file
}
```

**Please let me know if anything is not clear and help me to solve this issue.
Thanks**

Comment: Instead of using `>` you could use the pipe. `Get-Hash e$ | Out-file C:\Direct\Reverse\Out.txt -Append` Append should stop it from overwriting what it already there.

Comment: @Matt yes File1.txt contains list of file names not the full file path

Comment: So you are searching your C: drive for the files `Data1.txt` and `SqlData.txt` and outputting the hash of both files to `out.txt`?

Comment: Yes including its filename and path as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchPath = Get-Content "C:\Direct\Dir1.txt" 
Get-Content -Path "C:\Direct\File1.txt" | ForEach-Object{
    # For each line in the file. Create a custom object that contains all the needed data.
    $theFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter $searchPath  -Recurse  -Force -ErrorVariable FailedItems -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    [pscustomobject] @{
        'File Name' = $_
        'Path' = $theFile.DirectoryName
        'Hash'= Get-Hash $theFile
    }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -notypeinformation | Out-File C:\Direct\Reverse\Out.txt -Append
```

1. `$searchPath` to get the `c:\` you spoke of. If thats all it contains then you dont really need it. But i could see other searches down the road so i am leaving it as requested. This only needs to be called once so i took it out of the `ForEach` loop.
2. We get the contents of the file which should be a list of individual files.
3. For each of those files names we search the `$searchPath`. *I think we could make the Get-ChildItem call better. I need to investigate that.*
4. Create a custom object with all the details we need.
5. Convert the custom object to a csv entity so the output will be clean.
6. Put those custom objects to file. We use `-Append` to make sure it does not overwrite any details.

**Caveats**
I just whipped this up to wet your whistle.
I need to get `Get-Hash` as i don't have it so i cannot test this properly. I wont be able to update to 4.0 anytime soon. 
This does not do any error checking ie. if files exist. I would suggest that in any production script.

Comment: i am getting this error while running your above script.
    The term 'For-EachObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmd
    let, function, script file, or operable program.

However my mentioned Script is working as expected after adding Pipe instead of > but now i am facing one more issue that is at the time of Exporting Result in to Out.txt file i am trying to save the result in the separated File Names which i am fetching using below code at the starting

$arr = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Direct\*.txt"

Comment: Oh ok. The first error was due to a typo. It's actually `ForEach-Object`.I will incorporate your last comment as best i can.

Comment: Now it makes sense what `$c = $objFile.Name` is for. Could you not just `C:\Direct\Reverse\c$` from your original example?